# How to prevent ListView sorting from blocking the program

Tags: c#, sorting, listview

I have a list with hundreds items,
when I try to sort the items, it always blocking my program.
It' so too **annoying**.
I try to use Task.Run(), It doesn't work.

```
private void resultListView_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
{
    // doesn't work
    Task.Run(() => ListViewOperate((ListView)sender, ListViewOP.SORT));

    // doesn't work
    resultListView.BeginUpdate();
    ListViewOperate((ListView)sender, ListViewOP.SORT);
    resultListView.EndUpdate();
}


private delegate void ListViewOperateDelegate(System.Windows.Forms.ListView liv, 
     ListViewOP op);
private void ListViewOperate(System.Windows.Forms.ListView liv, ListViewOP op)
{ 
   if (liv.InvokeRequired)
        {
            var addDele = new ListViewOperateDelegate(ListViewOperate);
            liv.Invoke(addDele, new object[] { liv, op});
   }
   else
   {
      if (op == ListViewOP.SORT)
      {
         liv.BeginUpdate();
         liv.Sort();
         liv.EndUpdate();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why don't call it async ?

Comment: @Elikill58 that doesn't work, because you must add/remove listview items on the UI thread.

Comment: [Use Visual C# to sort a ListView control by using a column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/sort-listview-by-column). _Virtual Mode_ is a better approach for big collections.

Comment: If sorting "hundreds of items" takes any noticeable time there is something wrong going on. Sorting a *million* ints takes about 100ms for me. I would suggest doing some profiling to check what is taking time. Perhaps your objects are **very** expensive to compare? or swapping items are triggering some kind of updating?

Comment: @JonasH sorry about that, I am not English, it's ten-thousands.

Comment: @Jared DC the same applies to ten-thousands. ideally programs should respond within 50ms, but 200-500ms might be acceptable in some cases. And sorting 10^5 items should not take more than 10ms, as long as the comparator is simple, so it is likely that the problem is somewhere else. So I would suggest to *Measure first*

Comment: @JonasH you are right, not sorting cause block ,please help me at [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68377387/c-sharp-how-to-deal-with-listview-foreach-block-program

Answer (score 3):

The trick you are trying to use, doesn't work here, because you are starting the
ListViewOperator on a thread/task but the callback checks if it is started on the UI thread. If it isn't on the UI thread, invoke it on the UI thread. So what benefits did you gain?  none..

You should check the [Virtual Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode?view=net-5.0). With the virtual mode you are able to sort it (a copy) of the list on a task/thread and then swap the list "variable" and trigger the listview to refresh it self.

Here is an [Example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42229/Virtual-Mode-ListView)