# c# How to deal with ListView foreach block program?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

c# How to deal with ListView Threading foreach program?
I try to update the Checked in List,
If I don't use Task.Run(Threading), it will block the program.
If I use Task.Run, It will cause the InvalidOperationException

```
Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // Cause System.InvalidOperationException
                foreach (ListViewItem item in liv.Items) 
                {
                    var fullPath = item.SubItems["fullPath"].Text;
                    
                    foreach (var gl in geminiFileStructListForLV)
                    {
                        if (fullPath.Equals(gl.fullPath))
                        {
                            gl.Checked = item.Checked;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: I don't think that you've provided enough code to indicate why it is blocking in the first place.

Comment: Try first to update your ListView between [BeginUpdate()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate) and [EndUpdate()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.endupdate) calls. Otherwise, the ListView Control has a [VirtualMode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode) that can increase its performance (since you only handle a small batch of items at a time and you only need to update its source of data). -- An example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61719931/7444103).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `gl.Checked = item.Checked;` is not permitted. Because you cannot modify members of a `foreach iteration variable`. You have to change your `foreach` to `for`

Secondly, Cross-Thread operations are not valid for Controls. It simply means you can't use a Control which was created by the Main thread inside another thread

The most simple way to avoid blocking the program by the loops is to call [`Application.DoEvents();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.doevents?view=net-5.0) in every cycle of your loop:

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in liv.Items)
{
    var fullPath = item.SubItems["fullPath"].Text;

    for(var i = 0; i < geminiFileStructListForLV.Length; i++)
    {
        if(fullPath.Equals(geminiFileStructListForLV[i].fullPath))
        {
            geminiFileStructListForLV[i].Checked = item.Checked;
        }

        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can modify value in foreach because the Check in class has set attribute.